# session_start(): Cannot find save handler 'mm' - session startup failed in /sites

Tags: php, apache

got issues with the following PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot find save handler 'mm' - session startup failed in /sites

Cannot find save handler 'mm': save handler: see :

well i do not know what this means:

but i found some texts that explain it:

> if you compile PHP using the --with-mm configuration, you can set the
>   session module to mm. This module uses shared memory for storing
>   sessions. If you wish to implement your own handler in PI IP, see the
>   session_set save handler function. string session_name(string naine)
>   The session_name function returns

cf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740791/php-configuration-to-enable-sessions

**question:** is this true - does the mm stand for a special configurations option?

well could it be that the wordpress configuration is trying to store the session data using something other than the default session data file handler.
Well i guess that there are very few real cases where we need to use a different session data handler, So the question is: should we set the wordpress configuration to use the default php session data file handler.

**Note:** i do not run this on shared web hosting - but on a root-server. 
What should i do now?

on a shared web hosting i could create a folder within the hosting directory tree, outside of the document root folder to hold the session data, then set the session.save_path setting to match this folder.

see some data out of the php-configuration – not sure if they help here;

```
Session Support     enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php_serialize php php_binary
Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 3600    3600
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    /dev/urandom    /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length  32  32
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  3600    3600
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    mm  mm
session.save_path   no value    no value
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_strict_mode Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

what to do now?

**update:** mmm you wrote:

> WordPress has it own session system and don't use the PHP one then you
>   have a problem of PHP configuratio

well what to do now!?

well

Comment: WordPress has it own session system and don't use the PHP one then you have a problem of PHP configuration

Comment: helllo dear mmm - i updated the treadstart - and added more infos about the current settings - anything what i need to change..!`?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your session can not be saved by your session save handler. As you see you are using `mm` session save handler which stands for Shared Memory.

From php.net:

> To use shared memory allocation (mm) for session storage configure PHP
>   --with-mm[=DIR] .

You probably need to install php Shared Memory extension to use this kind of session handler:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php

Default php session handler is file handler which store your session in files on file system. This handler do not need any additional extension.